# Define proof environment in thmtools

Tags: theorems, thmtools

I'm using [thmtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) for fancy-looking math environments. But I don't know how to redefine **proof** environment. I cannot find such topics in its documentation.

This is my LaTeX code snippet.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{section_color}{rgb}{0.35,0.0,0}
\definecolor{MyGray}{rgb}{0.96,0.97,0.98}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

% defining common style
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
qed=,
]{mystyle}

% defining theorem environment
\declaretheorem[
style=mystyle,
shaded={bgcolor=MyGray,padding=2mm,textwidth=0.98\textwidth}
]{theorem}

% defining claim environment
\declaretheorem[
sibling=theorem,
style=mystyle,
shaded={bgcolor=MyGray,padding=2mm,textwidth=0.98\textwidth}
]{claim}

\begin{document}
%title{Thmtools Example}

\begin{theorem}[Euler's identity]
$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Use Euler's formula $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Fermat's Last Theorem]
Ask Andrew Wiles.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want for the proof environment is:

1. It has the same style as other environments: same font, same boldface, and same text color
2. But it has no shaded background.
3. It can handle an argument so that the title 'Proof' can be changed, as shown in the second proof example.

How can I redefine proof environment using thmtools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way I've found is to redefine the `proof` environment, that is, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{section_color}{rgb}{0.35,0.0,0}
\definecolor{MyGray}{rgb}{0.96,0.97,0.98}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

% defining common style
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
qed=,
]{mystyle}

% defining theorem environment
\declaretheorem[
style=mystyle,
shaded={bgcolor=MyGray,padding=2mm,textwidth=0.98\textwidth}
]{theorem}

% defining claim environment
\declaretheorem[
sibling=theorem,
style=mystyle,
shaded={bgcolor=MyGray,padding=2mm,textwidth=0.98\textwidth}
]{claim}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%title{Thmtools Example}

\begin{theorem}[Euler's identity]
$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Use Euler's formula $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Fermat's Last Theorem]
Ask Andrew Wiles.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If the additional extra spacing in the margins used for theorems and claims should also be used for proofs, you can change the above redefinition to (thanks to Gonzalo Medina for suggesting it)

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \list{}{\leftmargin=1.25mm\itemindent=20pt\linewidth=0.975\textwidth%
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries
   #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces}
}{%
  \popQED\endlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

and you will obtain

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Will you make this into an answer with additional comments? `:)`

Comment: Is there suppose to be a  bigger vertical space between theorem and proof than between proof and proof?

Comment: Also, I don't get `Sætning 1` instead of `Theorem 1` as I would expect.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Would you ask a new question with your requirements? For the last, just add `name=Sætning` option in `\declaretheorem`