# Vertical spacing around theorem environment

Tags: spacing, theorems

Consider [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154889/15874) from karlkoeller:

```
\documentclass[danish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

% Colors.
\definecolor{section_color}{rgb}{0.35,0.0,0}
\definecolor{MyGray}{rgb}{0.96,0.97,0.98}

% Defining common style.
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove = 6pt,
  spacebelow = 6pt,
  headfont = \color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries,
  notefont = \mdseries,
  notebraces = {(}{)},
  bodyfont = \normalfont,
  postheadspace = 1em,
  qed = ,
]{mystyle}

% Defining theorem environment.
\declaretheorem[
  style = mystyle,
  name = S{\ae}tning,
  shaded = {
    bgcolor = MyGray,
    padding = 2mm,
    textwidth = 0.98\textwidth
}
]{theorem}

% Defining claim environment.
\declaretheorem[
  sibling = theorem,
  style = mystyle,
  shaded = {
    bgcolor = MyGray,
    padding = 2mm,
    textwidth = 0.98\textwidth
  }
]{claim}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \list{}{\leftmargin=1.25mm\itemindent=20pt\linewidth=0.975\textwidth%
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries
   #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces}
}{%
  \popQED\endlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Eulers identitet]
$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Brug Eulers formul; $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Bevis for Fermats sidste S{\ae}tning]
Sp{\o}rg Sir Andrew John Wiles.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As can be seen in the screenshot, the vertical spacing around the theorem environment is bigger than the spacing around the proof environment; how do I change it to be the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create an `mdframed` environment which simulates the one created for theorems:

```
\newmdenv[
  leftmargin = -2pt,
  rightmargin = -2pt,
  innerleftmargin = 2mm,
  innerrightmargin = 2mm,
  innertopmargin = 6pt,
  innerbottommargin = 6pt,
  skipabove = 1pt,
  skipbelow = 10pt,
  linewidth = 0pt,
  backgroundcolor = white
]{proofbox}
```

and then apply it to the redefinition of `proof`

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\proofbox\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse\endproofbox
}
\makeatother
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[danish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}

% Colors.
\definecolor{section_color}{rgb}{0.35,0.0,0}
\definecolor{MyGray}{rgb}{0.96,0.97,0.98}

% Defining common style.
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove = 6pt,
  spacebelow = 6pt,
  headfont = \color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries,
  notefont = \mdseries,
  notebraces = {(}{)},
  bodyfont = \normalfont,
  postheadspace = 1em,
  qed = ,
]{mystyle}

% Defining theorem environment.
\declaretheorem[
  style = mystyle,
  name = S{\ae}tning,
  shaded = {
    bgcolor = MyGray,
    padding = 2mm,
    textwidth = 0.98\textwidth
}
]{theorem}

% Defining claim environment.
\declaretheorem[
  sibling = theorem,
  style = mystyle,
  shaded = {
    bgcolor = MyGray,
    padding = 2mm,
    textwidth = 0.98\textwidth
  }
]{claim}

\newmdenv[
  leftmargin = -2pt,
  rightmargin = -2pt,
  innerleftmargin = 2mm,
  innerrightmargin = 2mm,
  innertopmargin = 6pt,
  innerbottommargin = 6pt,
  skipabove = 1pt,
  skipbelow = 10pt,
  linewidth = 0pt,
  backgroundcolor = white
]{proofbox}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\proofbox\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \color{section_color}\sffamily\bfseries
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse\endproofbox
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Eulers identitet]
$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Brug Eulers formul; $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Bevis for Fermats sidste S{\ae}tning]
Sp{\o}rg Sir Andrew John Wiles.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you change the background color to

```
backgroundcolor = MyGray
```

you can appreciate the result:

[image]